# Why can't I get Angularjs to work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying angularjs for the first time and I am having trouble getting it to actually work..I think.

I am doing the exercises on a website and when I run it on the website it works, but when I try to follow along and write it myself in my own files I can't get it to work.

For example: when I type this "{{store.product.name}}" it prints exactly that including the braces, but on the site it prints out "Azurite"

my code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="test">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
    <div>
      <h3>{{store.product.name}}</h3>
      <h3>{{store.product.price}</h3>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
(function(){
  var gem = { name: 'Azurite', price: 2.95 };
  var app = angular.module('gemStore', []);
  app.controller('StoreController', function(){
        this.product = gem;
  });
})();
```

Comment: What version of angular are you using? Also check your browser console,and share the errors you are getting

Comment: Are you running a server locally?  If not, that may be the issue.

Comment: simple, first call angular.min.js then app.js

Comment: Because you are calling your app.js first. Reference the angular.min.js before your app.js

Comment: yes always your anularjs script should load first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app name is incorrect.

```
<html ng-app="gemStore"> </html>
```

`gemStore` is the name for your app not `test`.

Comment: I feel like an idiot haha, I could have sworn that I had it right. Thanks for the help, it ended up working!

Answer (score 1):

You shuld close the double curly brace

You have

```
<h3>{{store.product.price}</h3>
```

Should be

```
<h3>{{store.product.price}}</h3>
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

when you working with angular app .

You need angularJs script first and others should follow.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="gemStore">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

</head>
  <body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
    <div>
      <h3>{{store.product.name}}</h3>
      <h3>{{store.product.price}</h3>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

let me know if you need any help.

For reference you can see this plunker:

> http://plnkr.co/edit/28gANOyhz5mLb7zkhu9W?p=preview